# YouTube API: music information

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to collect music data from YouTube videos. Some videos have a box that lists "Music in this video", including the song title and artist, shown below.

[image: example-music-information]

From the API documentation, I cannot figure out how to extract this music information. E.g. [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) shows how to extract some information related to a YouTube video, but it does not include the music information.

Does anyone know about how to get the music information?

Comment: This is a recurrent question on SO under the tags [tag:youtube-data-api] or [tag:youtube-api]. As far as I know, unfortunately, the YouTube Data API does not provide the info you're looking for via any of its endpoints. But, I also (may) recommend you to file a feature request to Google via its [own issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/) for to see whether this feature could be offered upon an API update.

Comment: [I have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652266) the same question on StackOverflow, let me know if it doesn't fit your needs.